# Xcode 6.1.1 Toolbar Icon and Text doesn't show

Tags: osx-yosemite, xcode6.1

In Xcode 6.1.1 the Icon and Text doesnt show. It just shows the Icons. If if right click when the the icons are showing it just gives"hide toolbar" as the option and no option to show both Icons and Text.

This is very strange. If I use Xcode 5.x it shows the Icons and Text and right click on the toolbar works properly.

Anyone else having this issue? Also the same used to happen in 6.1 also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and click on 'Hide Toolbar', next you right click on the tool bar again and you can select 'Icon and Text'. Now you should have both Icon and Text as shows below;
[image]

[image]

I have a problem, it seems I have to click on 'Hide Toolbar' twice for Xcode to response.

Comment: Ya that happens to me too. I have to right click twice to get to the options above. That itself is strange on top of that even after selecting Icon and Text, it glitches a bit and then shows only the icons.

So for you it shows both Icons and Text on the toolbar after this???

Comment: Hmm you are right ! The 'Icon and Text' and 'Icon Only' show the same results. I always used Icon Only version since Xcode 5 so that's why it does not bother me. Hope they fixxx it soon.

Comment: Hmm. That is just plain silly of Apple. This same problem is there in 6.1 but they didnt try to fix it in 6.1.1. I mean why create an update. Thanks for confirming tho as I though that i was due to some corruption while installation.

Even preview.app is buggy. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160193/bug-in-preview-when-copying-and-pasting-an-image